# Symfony - entity - one field with two setter / getter?

Tags: php, symfony, entity

I want to have string type column (for bit manipulations) with two or more getter / setter, f. ex:

```
const STATUS_NEW         = 0b00001000;
const STATUS_NEW2        = 0b00000010;

/**
 * @var String
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="modelStatus", type="string", length=1, nullable=true)
 */
private $status;

public function getNew()
{
    return ($this->status and $this::NEW);
}

public function setNew(bool $set)
{
    if ($set) {
        $this->status = ($this->status | $this::STATUS_NEW);
    } else {
        $this->status = ($this->status & ~$this::STATUS_NEW);
    }
    return $this;
}

public function getNew2()
{
    return ($this->status and $this::NEW2);
}

public function setNew2(bool $set)
{
    if ($set) {
        $this->status = ($this->status | $this::NEW2);
    } else {
        $this->status = ($this->status & ~$this::NEW2);
    }
    return $this;
}
```

with form:

```
$builder->add('new', CheckboxType::class, [
    'required' => false,
->add('new2', CheckboxType::class, [
    'required' => false,
])
```

When I check checkboxes, it "enter" only the last setter, not in all:(

Sorry for my english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found a solution - error was in my "get function (it doesn't return correct value, so he thought that field wasn't changed).

Correct way to check if bit is set:
    return ($this->status & $this::STATUS_NEW ? true : false);

Comment: You can probably write `(bool) $this::STATUS_NEW` instead of `$this::STATUS_NEW ? true : false`.